# Expression of 'in other quarters'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Of course, Percival Brooks, the eldest son, would inherit the bulk of the old man's property and also probably the larger share in the business; he, too, was good-looking, more so than his brother; he, too, rode, danced, and talked well, but it was many years ago that mammas with marriageable daughters had given up all hopes of Percival Brooks as a probable son-in-law.
>
> That young man's infatuation for Maisie Fortescue, a lady of undoubted charm but very doubtful antecedents, who had astonished the London and Dublin music-halls with her extravagant dances, was too well known and too old-established to encourage any hopes **in other quarters**.

(source:  'Dublin Mystery', in the book "Old man in the corner", by Baroness Orczy.)

What does the *in other quarters* mean in this sentence?
Any other alternative expression for this?

Comment: You might instead say "in other single and eligible women (and their mothers)"—the idea being that all such other women are situated—literally and figuratively—in quarters elsewhere than at chez Fortescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **quar·ter**
>
> noun
>
> \R ˈkwȯr|tər, |tər sometimes by r-dissimilation -ȯ|; −R -ȯ(ə)|tə(r,
>   |tə(r\
>
> plural quarters
>
> 7 d (1) :  **a person or group not definitely specified**
>
> *had his instructions from a very high quarter*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

'in other quarters': in other people, in other (social) circles